# How to load or add refrence and use it in other app domain in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, appdomain

when i load my dll to my other app domain it is loaded correctly
but when i excute the exe which is need to the dll it throw exception

this code is from another question on StackOverFlow

my code :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AppDomain app = AppDomain.CreateDomain("seco");



        //my dll that i want to add to my app domain
        string path = @"D:\vs projects\ConsoleApplication17\ConsoleApplication17\bin\Debug\lom.dll";

        Type type = typeof(Proxy);
        var asmLoaderProxy = (Proxy)app.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(

            type.Assembly.FullName, 

            type.FullName);


        asmLoaderProxy.GetAssembly(path); //load succed here 


        // the exe that needs to the dll 
        app.ExecuteAssembly("op.exe"); // -> throw exception FileNotFoundException here

        AppDomain.Unload(app);



        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Proxy 
    {
        public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
        {
            try
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
                // throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

what is my mistake ?
note -> the dll is has one class that has one mehtod that print " print hello in dll"

and the exe take instance from the class and call the method

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I make a test.

However, I find that I can run the code successfully without any exception.

Here I want to mention that we need to use absolute path about `"op.exe"`.

Like:`@"D:\sample\TestDll\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\op.exe"`

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks for replying , but i get the solution , it is working when i remove serializeble attribute from my proxy class and make it inherite from MarchalByRefObject and dont return value from Assemply.LoadFrom()